# Can Hyperledger Fabric Be Used To Create A Tradable Cryptocurrency?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, cryptocurrency

I believe it is possible to create a cryptocurrency with Hyperledger (Though a bit unconventional, perhaps). As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459696/cryptocurrency-based-on-hyperledger), chaincode can accomplish this. Would it then be possible for a token created in a Hyperledger network to be traded on exchanges, should they want to list the tokens?

What would be the downsides to attempting this? One might say that the network wouldn't be as public as others. Then again, neither is Ripple's XRP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Token feature in the alpha release of 2.0, you can check it out: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew.html#fabtoken

Comment: is alpha release of 2.0 stable or not?

Answer (score 0):

The platform-neutral Token Taxonomy Initiative overseen by the Enterprise Ethereum Alliance (EEA) has announced the publication of the Token Taxonomy Framework (TTF) V 1.0, which enables businesses and developers to universally understand and define what a token is in non-technical terms, regardless of how it is implemented.

Also check here [Can we create non-fungible tokens with Hyperledger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948910/can-we-create-non-fungible-tokens-with-hyperledger/58969057#58969057)