# Can we create non-fungible tokens with Hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ethereum

According to ERC-721

> ERC-721 is a free, open standard that describes how to build
>   non-fungible or unique tokens on the Ethereum blockchain. While most
>   tokens are fungible (every token is the same as every other token),
>   ERC-721 tokens are all unique.

Is there a provision on a permissioned blockchain like hyperledger for `non-fungile tokens`?

Answer (score 2):

The platform-neutral **Token Taxonomy Initiative** overseen by the **Enterprise Ethereum Alliance (EEA)** has announced the publication of the **Token Taxonomy Framework (TTF) v1.0**, which enables businesses and developers to universally understand and define what a token is in non-technical terms, regardless of how it is implemented.

Users of the TTF can create a new type of token from a set of reusable, cross-industry components, including existing token definitions, creating a specification that includes all of the business ingredients for any implementation.

Using standardized terms and definitions to both understand and build token-based systems, the TTF enables businesses and developers to universally design the next-generation of token-based business goods and services – without requiring an understanding of industry jargon or coding.

The taxonomy uses these terms for all tokens:

- Token Template - describes a token based on its type and what
  capabilities or restrictions a token created from the template would
  have (i.e. **Fractional Fungible Template**).

A template has two parts:

- **Template Formula** - a set of reusable taxonomy components that, when
  combined, is used to classify and describe how to work with a token.
- **Template Definition** - is derived from a formula, filling in the
  details to define a token that can be used to deploy as a class (i.e. Cryptocurrency Token Definition)

Also

- **Token Class** - a deployed token from a Template (i.e. Bitcoin
  created from the cryptocur rency template).
- **Token Instance** - a
  single token in a Token Class (i.e. satoshi balance in your
  cryptocurrency wallet)

> The taxonomy uses symbols to represent token bases and possible
> behaviors that are used to create a token definition as a formula. The
> symbols and token formulas can be used to create hierarchical
> relationships useful for visualizations, and to aid in learning and
> design. The two base types can also be combined in different ways to
> create hybrid token definitions.
>
> **Fungible**
>
> - Physical cash or a cryptocurrency is a good example of a fungible token.
>   These tokens have interchangeable value with one another,where any quantity of them has the same value as another equal quantity if they are in the same class or series. A fungible token is
>   identified by f symbol.
>
> **Non-fungible**
>
> - A non-fungible token is unique. Hence a non-fungible token is not    interchangeable with other tokens of the same type as they typically have different values. A property title is a good example of a non-fungible token where the title to a broken-down shack is not of the same value as the title to a mansion. A fungible token is identified by n symbol.

View the TTF V 1.0 and draft specification documents on the TTI website at https://tokentaxonomy.org/resources/.

[Here](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/download/attachments/24775128/TTF-Presentation.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1574277519000&api=v2) is the technical overview of the framework

Microsoft has announced TTF support in [Azure Blockchain Tokens](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/blockchain-tokens/), which simplifies the ability to define, create and manage compliant tokens based on TTF standards.

Comment: The website is down

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do this, since Hyperledger is a permissioned blockchain and Ethereum a public one?

Anyways, if you mean to create an asset with a unique identifier, you could create a smart contract with a ID parameter that implements your request, so everytime you try to create the idem with that same ID, the contract reject your request.

Comment: Ethereum is too public. I'm referring to a centralized blockchain alternative that could hide functions in smart contract and still issue tokens.

Comment: Then I think you can implement it as I said.